# Json Schema for a json schema with complex conditions

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

I need to validate that a given JSON schema instance is following certain rules.
most of the rules can be checked against other schema but I couldn't check 2 conditions by using a schema:

1. for each 'object' type, each property in 'properties' must be also in the 'required' list.
2. '$schema' must be and can only be in the root of the schema.

In fact, I have already succeeded validate these conditions by creating [custom validators](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/creating/) in a python script, but I wondered,
Is this possible to check these conditions purely by using JSON schema?

if you curios you can see the current schema I'm using, although it's not necessary for my question:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",

    "definitions": {
        "types": {
            "object": {
                "_comment": "object type",
                "isType": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "type": {"enum": ["object"]},
                    "properties": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "additionalProperties": {"$ref": "#/definitions/schema"},
                    },
                    "additionalProperties": {"enum": [False]},
                    "required": {"type": "array"},
                    "description": {"type": "string", "maxLength": 128},
                    "$id": {"type": "string", "maxLength": 128}

                },
                "dependencies": {
                    "properties": ["required"],
                    "required": ["properties"]
                },
                "required": ["additionalProperties"],
                "allRequired": True,  # custom validator for requiring all properties
                "additionalProperties": False
            },
         ... # extra types that not really relevant
        },

        "schema": {
            "oneOf": [
                {"$ref": "#/definitions/types/object"},
                {"$ref": "#/definitions/types/string"},
                {"$ref": "#/definitions/types/number"},
                {"$ref": "#/definitions/types/array"},
                {"$ref": "#/definitions/types/enum"},
                {"$ref": "#/definitions/types/anyOf"},
            ],

        },
    },

    "type": "object",
    "$ref": "#/definitions/schema"
}
```

---

if you don't know if it's possible, maybe you can help me with one of these questions:

1. Is it possible to refer to the current instance being validated(similarly that '$ref':"#" is referring to the current schema)
2. Is it possible somehow using the '[dependencies](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html?highlight=dependencies#dependencies)' validator somehow to validate condition 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. for each 'object' type, each property in 'properties' must be also in the 'required' list.

Can't be done, because ...

> 1. Is it possible to refer to the current instance being validated(similarly that '$ref':"#" is referring to the current schema)

No. There was a proposal for a keyword like that called `$data`, but there were too many issues with the concept, so it never materialized.

> 2. Is it possible somehow using the 'dependencies' validator somehow to validate condition 1?

No.

> 2. '$schema' must be and can only be in the root of the schema.

This one you can do. Basically, you create the "schema" definition with everything defined. Then you can extend the "schema" to require `$schema` in the root schema or forbid `$schema` in sub-schemas.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",

  "allOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/schema" }],
  "required": ["$schema"],

  "definitions": {
    "schema": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "$id": { "type": "string", "format": "uri" },
        "$schema": { "type": "string", "format": "uri" },
        "properties": {
          "type": "object",
          "additionalProperties": { "$ref": "#/definitions/sub-schema" }
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "sub-schema": {
      "allOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/schema" }],
      "not": { "required": ["$schema"] }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer friend!

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible with JSON Schema. You cannot reference instance data.

Comment: ok, thank you, and what about requiring `$schema` only on root?

Comment: Might actually be possible. I'll have a play and get back to you.